# Visualforce Pages are not showing up in Lightning App Builder - Record Home Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, summer-16, app-builder, record-home-page

In Summer 16 release, we have ability to Create Record Home Pages for any Object. I was looking for that in my dev org and when I went in to create one I found that none of my Visualforce Pages are showing up in Visualforce Component ~ Visualforce Page Name dropdown.

Now, the dropdown's Help Text clearly says that the VF page should have "Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages" enabled for the page for it to show up here, and I've that checkbox enable din my Pages.

The same VF page is shown when I open System Default Layout in Lightning Experience, and in S1. But for some reason I cannot have that Page in my drodown selection for a Custom Tab I want to add to Standard Detail View for LE users.

Has someone else also experienced this issue and is there a workaround for this or am I missing anything here in my config?

---

**Update**

This looks like a bug to me. I was able to display the Missing Pages not showing up in App Builder, if I **remove** the `StandardController` assigned to that VF page. Since I was hoping to see the Record Pages in LE to show up all VF apegs Only for that Object in that Object record's Context, and if I were to remove the `StandardController` for the Custom tabs to show me a vf page which does not limit data in the page according to the current record's ID value, it seems this is not implemented right way or at least not working as desired :(

Here is an excerpt from online Help Documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages_considerations.htm&language=en_US

> When you open a Lightning Experience record page in Lightning App
>   Builder, you see only the components in the palette that are available
>   for the object tied to that page.

So, my understanding of this seems right and the app builder is not working as needed to be.

Comment: Did you create a tab for the visualforce page? Haven't tried to use this feature yet, but it's needed in other places, so is likely needed here too.

Comment: Yes, one page have Tab created for it (being displayed in Salesforce1 Navigation menu) and that too is not showing up in the dropdown.

Comment: @crmprogdev, I just updated new information I found regarding this issue to my question description above.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bug to me. Those pages can't operate without their controllers. I'd expect them to be encapsulated in a Lightning I-Frame and served from a VF server that sends them to the Lightning Server as a pass thru for final delivery to the end user's Browser Window. @DougChasman

Comment: Thanks guys. I just saw a Known Issue opened for this issue I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that Salesforce has accepted this as Bug and a Known issue has been opened here - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYo9QAG